# My colors look awful, I can't tell why

Tags: color-grading

I'm an amateur that recently made a video clip using the *DJI Mavic Pro* drone.
The footage itself turned out great, but the coloring is off.

The problem is, I can't tell what exactly is off, it just looks awful.
I tried to do some color correction in my video software, but I couldn't get it right.

Here is a single frame of the video, with no color correction:

[image: Snapshot of the video]

I came here to ask what parameters I have to consider to make it look more natural, or if that isn't enough, what I should change when recording the video. (exposure, filters?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Awful' is pretty extreme - I don't actually think it looks that bad.

Perhaps it's a little bit over exposed (the car is almost glowing, it's that white) so you might want to consider an ND filter if you're filming outdoors (and you can get one of those for your drone).

Colour-wise, it does look like it's tipping towards the blue-end of the spectrum. Maybe try throwing a little more yellow/orange into the mix. However, that could just be my monitor. Do, please, check your monitor settings, too, they may be throwing off your perception.

This guy seems to know his stuff in regards to Mavic colour grading:

Maybe give that a watch and see if it helps :)

Comment: Thank you, I ordered ND filters and found my screen to have weird color representation.